# Adding rects in list for displaying in 7-segment digits in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I had two python files one for all the data that made previously and the other file of functions to display the data properly on screen using pygame.

**--Functioning--**

My idea is that the display of the segments is named alphabetically A,B,C,D,E,F,G
[image: PLZ refer to this image]

Here, till now every segment is displaying but if you see in my data.py code you can see there is a dictionary called 'final_data' where each number has it's binary code which simply means "How many segments had to glow..." ***Note:- '1' means to glow and '0' means to not glow, you can say these are buttons.** each button has a list of [x,y,width,height] to get display on the screen.* I also give the binaries and there positions. The dictionary is working properly the problem is in it's implementation in my second file 'functions.py'.

**--*Code*--**

*My first file is data.py and the code is......*

```
nums = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

binaries = ([1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1])

positions = ([200,110,10,50],[200,170,10,50],[150,220,50,10],[140,170,10,50],[140,110,10,50],[150,100,50,10],[150,160,50,10])


final_data = {'0':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10]], "0": [[150, 160, 50, 10]]},
'1':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50]], "0": [[150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]]},
'2':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]], "0": [[200, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50]]},
'3':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]], "0": [[140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50]]},
'4':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 160, 50, 10]], "0": [[150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10]]},
'5':{"1": [[200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]],"0": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [140, 170, 10, 50]]},
'6':{"1": [[200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 160, 50, 10]],"0": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10]]},
'7':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10]], "0": [[150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 160, 50, 10]]},
'8':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 170, 10, 50], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]]},
'9':{"1": [[200, 110, 10, 50], [200, 170, 10, 50], [150, 220, 50, 10], [140, 110, 10, 50], [150, 100, 50, 10], [150, 160, 50, 10]], "0": [[140, 170, 10, 50]]}
}

"""
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
1,1,1,1,1,1,0
1,1,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,1,0,0,1,1
1,1,0,0,1,0,1
0,1,1,0,1,1,1
0,1,1,1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,0,1,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,0,1,1,1
"""
```

*My second file functions.py*

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

size = width,height = 400,400
running = True
segments = []
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

def draw_rect(x,y,width,height):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(x,y,width,height))

def digits():
    #A
    draw_rect(200,110,10,50)
    #B
    draw_rect(200,170,10,50)
    #C
    draw_rect(150,220,50,10)
    #D
    draw_rect(140,170,10,50)
    #E
    draw_rect(140,110,10,50)
    #F
    draw_rect(150,100,50,10)
    #G
    draw_rect(150,160,50,10)



while running:
    screen.fill((148,241,251))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_q]:
        run = False
        sys.exit()

    digits()
    pygame.display.update()
```

**please tell me in comments do you like my idea? and is the format of asking question is correct. **

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `final_data` at all. Just write a function `draw_digit`:

```py
def draw_digit(surf, color, i):
    for j, on in enumerate(binaries[i]):
        if on:
            pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, positions[j])
```

And call it like this:

```py
draw_digit(screen, "black", 0)
```

[image]

Add an additional `offset` argument to display multiple digits in a row:

```py
def draw_digit(surf, color, offset, i):
    for j, on in enumerate(binaries[i]):
        if on:
            pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, pygame.Rect(positions[j]).move(offset, 0))
```

```py
draw_digit(screen, "black", 0, 2)
draw_digit(screen, "black", 100, 3)
```

[image]

---

Minimal example:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-7SegementDisplay](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-7SegementDisplay#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

*data.py*

```py
binaries = ([1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,0,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1])

positions = ([200,110,10,50],[200,170,10,50],[150,220,50,10],[140,170,10,50],[140,110,10,50],[150,100,50,10],[150,160,50,10])
```

*functions.py*

```py
import pygame, sys
from data import *

pygame.init()

size = width,height = 400,400
run = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_digit(surf, color, offset, i):
    for j, on in enumerate(binaries[i]):
        if on:
            pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, pygame.Rect(positions[j]).move(offset, 0))

count = 0  
while run:
    clock.tick(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((148,241,251))
    draw_digit(screen, "black", 0, count // 10)
    draw_digit(screen, "black", 100, count % 10)
    count += 1
    if count >= 100:
        count = 0
    pygame.display.update()
```